# Tensor flow Camera Demo takes more time on an android device. How to optimize it?

Tags: tensorflow

An custom model takes around 4 seconds for running the Tensor Flow (TF) module of TF camera demo on a Lenovo Yoga Tab 3 tablet https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/android
It is after optimizing the interface using TF tools.

How to improve the latency? Can the image size to TF be reduced? Now it takes 299x299 image as input. If "Yes" what is the recommended image size? or could any in-building TF optimizing technique be used?

Comment: I too am having inference time issues. I find the default app to be pretty fast but any custom models to be extremely slow even when the models are supposedly similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To improve the latency, perhaps you can try the 8-bit quantization tools provided by TensorFlow. They have a special tool just to do this: **Graph Transform** You can read more [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms).

For instance, this is what I do to my frozen model before I build it into an APK:

```
/home/kwotsin/tensorflow-android/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms/transform_graph \
--in_graph=./frozen_model_mobilenet.pb \
--out_graph=./quantized_model_mobilenet.pb \
--inputs='Placeholder_only' \
--outputs='MobileNet/Predictions/Softmax' \
--transforms='
  add_default_attributes
  strip_unused_nodes(type=float, shape="1,299,299,3")
  remove_nodes(op=Identity, op=CheckNumerics)
  fold_constants(ignore_errors=true)
  fold_batch_norms
  fold_old_batch_norms
  quantize_weights
  quantize_nodes
  strip_unused_nodes
  sort_by_execution_order'
```

To change the input size, I guess that will depend on what input size your model requires from the start. Currently, for my app, I use an image size of 299 as well and I can say the inference speed is very fast, typically under 1 second (of course, this depends on hardware as well. I ran it on an LG G3). If your model takes in a batch of tensors with shape [None, 299, 299, 3], then I guess your image size needs to be 299. Otherwise, you can try changing the image size in the `ClassifierActivity.java` file.

I don't think there's a recommended image size, since the classifier performance will depend on the task required to be done. For example, if you're doing a very simple task of simply classifying colors, I don't think you require a very high resolution image to do it. On the other hand, if you try to classify objects with very similar appearance, a larger image size will probably help in giving your classifier more information. Again, this depends on what training your model has done.

Comment: I used TF transform_graph function with and without optimize for interface function, but results generated are not the same as original and are incorrect. Seems this function has hardware dependency and is not working on my Lenovo Tablet at least